# Message in Ajax Update Progress Disappears fast

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to apply an update progress template in my detailview and everything is working fine but the update progress shows up quickly and disappears right away.  Is there a way to display the message in slow motion so the users can read it.  I am trying to slow it down little bit and give the user a chance to read it.  I was changing the Display After property from 50 to 10 but still the message disappears fast.   thanks

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true" DisplayAfter="10" >
            <ProgressTemplate>
            Your changes has been saved successfully….. 
            </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:DetailsView ID=1222

......

 </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I think update progress is used wrongly here. What happens if the update/insert didn't succeed, user still will be able to see the same progress statement. So, better to replace it with label status message and use progress bar to show progress. I think this issue has caused you to ask this question :-)

Comment: You could use a [`jQuery` fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) for your UpdateProgress.

Comment: i am having some problem, can u show me how u apply that in my UpdateProgress?  thanks

Comment: +1 to sundeep's comment, just put in an progress indicator gif in ProgressTemplate and add a label to show the operation's result.

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayAfter` property is used to set the time *after* which ProgressTemplate is displayed.
If I am getting you right that you want to delay the time during which message appears on the screen, then you can try adding [`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) method in the operation's logic to delay the message time.

Apart from that another way to do it would be by using [`beginRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event and adding the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.setTimeout) into it.